# Turn 2nd player from a bubble to a girl

Tags: guacamelee

I am trying to configure my game to 2 players in my PC.

I don't have a Xbox controller, so I followed [these instructions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RXroedRzfeU).

When I press enter a bubble appears as second player but I have pressed all keys from my keyboard and it doesn't turn into a girl.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't played the co-op, but I suspected that, as in many recent co-op platformers, player 1 needs to pop that bubble by hitting it for player 2 to (re)spawn. I just confirmed this by a quick YouTube search. You can see the instructions and how it works around 12:10 [in this video](https://youtu.be/gDQhrtCTiek?t=12m10s).